# Different output of sha1 from python3 and bash

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, sha1

I would like to count hash sha1 from word `hello`. I am using hashlib in python3 but the output is different in bash.
Python output:

```
hashlib.sha1(b"hello").hexdigest()
'aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d'
```

Bash output:

```
echo "hello" | sha1sum 
f572d396fae9206628714fb2ce00f72e94f2258f  -
```

When I check sha1 online, I receive result:

```
aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d
```

So I assume, the right hash is from python but why I receive wrong hash from bash? Could anybody explain me this problem?

Comment: The bash version is including a \n. Try `echo -n "hello" | sha1sum`

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I'd recommend using `printf '%s'` instead of `echo -n` -- depending on a variety of factors, the `echo` command *might* just print "-n " as part of the output string, leaving you even more confused than before. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) for some more info.